# c# creating a dynamically anonymous types (var)

Tags: c#, winforms, types

I need to create a anonymous type (HAS to be a var). Like this:

```
var sizes = new { 
    size = new { Medium = "1", Large = "-3", XL = "10%" } 
};
```

It has to be dynamically so the next time this could also happen:

```
var sizes = new { 
    size = new { 3XL = "5", 4XL = "5%", 5XL = "-10%" } 
};
```

How do I do this in C# winforms?

How do i fill in the var sizes? It has to be in this order!

Comment: and why are u doing this?

Comment: Please, have a look at `ExpandoObject` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Another possibility is `enum` and `Dictionary<K,V>`

Comment: It is going through a webservice with PHP. It does not work with the XML-RPC webservice

Comment: When i use the object:

var sizes = new { 
    size = new { 3XL = "5", 4XL = "5%", 5XL = "-10%" } 
};

It works. But now it hast the dynamic

Comment: @Ekrem If you're sending it to a webservice then you don't need an anonymous object, you just need some specific string data that you're either sending or receiving over a network connection.

Comment: But it does not work with a string because the webservice expects a object like this one. I have tested like 100 x and this is the only object that works :(

Comment: Web services can't expect an object. HTTP has no concept of strong types.

Comment: My question was is there a way to create this anonymous type dynamically?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the service expects a object like the Associative Array. Can you do this with the **ExpandoObject** do you how to setup it up. Just like my example: var sizes = new { 
    size = new { 3XL = "5", 4XL = "5%", 5XL = "-10%" } 
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dynamic type at runtime which contains methods and properties of any type using `System.Reflection.Emit`, you can assign default values into your properties within the dynamic type created. This is not a trivial exercise and it needs some work, but when you have the base code complete using it in your code is easy.

First you need to attach your dynamic type to your current `AppDomain`.

```
private AssemblyName _assemblyName;
private AssemblyBuilder _asssemblyBuilder;

private ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder;
private Dictionary<SignatureBuilder, Type> _classes;

private ReaderWriterLock _rwLock;
private TypeBuilder _typeBuilder;
private string _typeName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="moduleName">The name of the assembly module.</param>
    public DynamicTypeBuilder(string moduleName)
    {
        // Make sure the page reference exists.
        if (moduleName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("moduleName");

        // Create the nw assembly
        _assemblyName = new AssemblyName(moduleName);
        _asssemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(_assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        // Create only one module, therefor the
        // modile name is the assembly name.
        _moduleBuilder = _asssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(_assemblyName.Name);

        // Get the class unique signature.
        _classes = new Dictionary<SignatureBuilder, Type>();
        _rwLock = new ReaderWriterLock();
    }
```

The dynamic property class can be

```
/// <summary>
/// Dynamic property builder, with value assigned.
/// </summary>
public class DynamicPropertyValue
{
    object value;
    string name;
    Type type;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the property.</param>
    /// <param name="type">The type of the property</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the property.</param>
    public DynamicPropertyValue(string name, Type type, object value)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, the property name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, the property type.
    /// </summary>
    public Type Type
    {
        get { return type; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, the property value.
    /// </summary>
    public object Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }
}
```

The dynamic method class can be

```
/// <summary>
/// Dynamic method builder.
/// </summary>
public class DynamicMethod
{
    string name;
    IEnumerable<Type> parameters;
    Type returnType;
    Action<TypeBuilder> buildAction = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the method.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The collection parameter types.</param>
    /// <param name="returnType">The return type.</param>
    public DynamicMethod(string name, IEnumerable<Type> parameters, Type returnType)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

        this.name = name;
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.returnType = returnType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the method.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The collection parameter types.</param>
    /// <param name="returnType">The return type.</param>
    /// <param name="buildAction">The build action.</param>
    public DynamicMethod(string name, IEnumerable<Type> parameters, Type returnType, Action<TypeBuilder> buildAction)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

        this.name = name;
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.returnType = returnType;
        this.buildAction = buildAction;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, the method name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, the collection of parameters
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Type> Parameters
    {
        get { return parameters; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, the return type.
    /// </summary>
    public Type ReturnType
    {
        get { return returnType; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, build action.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<TypeBuilder> BuildAction
    {
        get { return buildAction; }
    }
}
```

Start the create process.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new instance of the dynamic type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typeName">The name of the type.</param>
    /// <param name="properties">The collection of properties to create in the type.</param>
    /// <param name="methods">The collection of methods to create in the type.</param>
    /// <returns>The new instance of the type.</returns>
    public object Create(string typeName, IEnumerable<DynamicPropertyValue> properties, IEnumerable<DynamicMethod> methods)
    {
        // Make sure the page reference exists.
        if (typeName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("typeName");
        if (properties == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("properties");
        if (methods == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("methods");

        _typeName = typeName;

        // Create the dynamic type collection
        List<DynamicProperty> prop = new List<DynamicProperty>();
        foreach (DynamicPropertyValue item in properties)
            prop.Add(new DynamicProperty(item.Name, item.Type));

        // Return the create type.
        object instance = CreateEx(typeName, prop.ToArray(), methods);
        PropertyInfo[] infos = instance.GetType().GetProperties();

        // Assign each type value
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in infos)
            info.SetValue(instance, properties.First(u => u.Name == info.Name).Value, null);

        // Return the instance with values assigned.
        return instance;
    }
```

If this is something you can use the complete source code for the dynamic type builder can be found at https://github.com/nequeo/misc/blob/master/csharp/DynamicTypeBuilder.cs

Comment: Hi @D.Zadravec thank you for your help. I am looking at this advanced source but it is hard for me (sorry) to set it back to the :

var sizes = new { size = new { 3XL = "5", 4XL = "5%", 5XL = "-10%" } };

Do you have a example with the source code above?

Comment: Sample can be found at [link](https://github.com/nequeo/misc/blob/master/csharp/DynamicTypeBuilderTest.zip)

Comment: thank you veryyyy much for the Sample :) This did the job! With the debugging sometimes the solutions crashes but this worked great for me. :)